# Offline ovi map in desktop application?

Tags: nokia

I asked a Map related question on Stack Overflow:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948710/offline-ovi-map-in-desktop-application

To provide more details, we are focussed on developing a commercial desktop application that will not have any internet connectivity. Though open source OpenStreetMaps seems like a good option, a commercial solution is preferred.

Comment: Ovi Maps API is now ironically Nokia Maps API - http://api.maps.nokia.com/places/quickstart.html - Does your solution have to be Nokia based? you mention you were considering Google? OpenStreetMap has offline abilities > http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Offline_Openstreetmap

Answer (score 3):

There is a difference between the APP (mobile) Nokia Maps and the API (web) for Nokia Maps

**The distinct difference is Offline APP is for Nokia Mobile/Tablet**

```
Can Nokia Maps be used in offline mode to avoid data costs?
```

Maps can be used offline to avoid data charges, however the following will not be available in Offline Mode:

```
View Satellite maps
View Terrain maps
Search the latest address/POI database
Real-time Traffic and Safety updates
Share your status, photos and location to your Facebook profile (Maps 3.03 and later)
Get Weather forecasts
See local event info from WCities (Maps 3.03 and later)
Access Lonely Planet city guides (Maps 3.03 and later)
Access the Michelin restaurant guide (Maps 3.03 and later)
Synchronize your locations with Nokia Maps on the internet
```

You can switch between Online and Offline mode by going to the Maps Settings and:

```
Select Internet or General
Select Connection or Go Online at Start-up
```

Please Note: Switching between Online and Offline mode in Maps will not prevent data charges through the user of Positioning settings such as AGPS and WiFi/Network positioning. These will need to be turned off in the Positioning Settings on your phone. Please see your phone manual for more information.

http://europe.nokia.com/support/product-support/maps-support/faq?comp=Nokiamaps308&name=Nokia+Maps&faqId=FA124244_en_US

From User Experience OFFLINE mode is only good if you have **all the data pre-loaded** on the **mobile device** for the area you are in/or interested in.

**You cannot use the Nokia WEB API (javascript) as a desktop application in an offline state.**

OpenStreetMap with your own tile render will allow you full offline support in a desktop environment:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software/Desktop